# Dropdown on button click using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to show dropdown on button click using material ui?

Currently, I'm able to do so but extra select field is getting populated which is not required. I don't want to hide select field with css.

Also, How can I change width, height, position and other properties of generated popover using material ui?
**codesandbox url:** https://codesandbox.io/s/du8mr

[current implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWAjS.png)

[popover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVB0b.png)

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this. https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#menulist-composition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Menu` component instead of a `Select` component.

You can change the `Menu` props using `MenuProps` which receives all Popover props.

From [Menu](https://material-ui.com/api/menu/) documentation:

> Any other props supplied will be provided to the root element ([Popover](https://material-ui.com/api/popover/)).

Comment: How can I change width, height, position and other properties of generated popover using material ui?

Comment: See this example for [Popover](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/#anchor-playground). If you do not want the `Select`, you can use a `Menu` which uses `Popover`  component under the hood and you can pass all the props to `Menu`. You can use `CSS` to set height and width for `Menu` component.

Comment: How can I pass "Popover" props via "Menu"?

Comment: You can pass all `Popover` props directly to `Menu` component. See the quotation above. Meaning you can do `<Menu anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'center', vertical: 'vertical'}} />`